# Setting attribute in a thymeleaf loop, based on a second list

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have the following thymeleaf code. 
transactionList and accountList are my model attributes

```
<tr th:each="transaction  : ${transactionList}" th:class="'account_' + ${transaction.accountId}">
    <td th:text="${transaction.transactionId}">0</td>
    <td>
        <select th:id="'account-' + ${transaction.transactionId}">
            <option th:each="account : ${accountList}"
                    th:value="${account.accountId}"
                    th:text="${account.name}"
                    th:selected="${transaction.accountId} == ${account.accountId}"/>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

My problem is setting the classname for the tr tag.
Its currently set to

```
th:class="'account_' + ${transaction.accountId}"
```

But I would like to change it so that it is the string 'account_' followed by the index of accountList where transaction.accountId == account.accountId.

So basically I would like to find which element of accountList has accountId equal to transaction.accountId.

So I would somehow have to loop through accountList each time before the th:class in the tr .

I could certainly add this to the objects contained in transactionList and be done with it, but it breaks abstraction, and I would prefer to do this on the front end.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a slick way of doing this, so I created a new model attribute that mapped accountIds to the index:

```
Map<String, Integer> accountIndexMap = new HashMap<>();
    IntStream.range(0, accountList.size())
            .forEach(i -> accountIndexMap.put(Long.toString(accountList.get(i).getAccountId()), i));

model.addAttribute("accountIndexMap", accountIndexMap);
```

Then in my thymeleaf page I changed the th:class to be:

```
<tr th:each="transaction  : ${transactionList}" th:class="'account_' + ${accountIndexMap.get('__${transaction.accountId}__')}">
```